# How to get username from JWT in DbContext using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

In **MyDbContext** I have method LogChanges, which log any changes in my *logs* table with this informations:

```
TableName = entityName,
IDRow = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(primaryKeys),
Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values),
Date = dateTimeNow,
Author = userFromJWT
```

I want to set Author to **User** which is authorized with JWT. From this part Excactly:

> "sub": "myUserName"

How can I get that username in **MyDbContext**? Maybe some kind of Depedency Injection?

Thanks in advance!

@Solution

**Startup.cs**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       // ...
       services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(options => {
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
          };
        });
      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
      //...
    }
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
// ...
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) : base(options) {
  _httpContext = httpContext;
}
//..
```

and to get name from claims (from "sub") from JWT I used

```
_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(
        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value
```

Comment: Given that your DBContext layer (project) is separated from Controller then   you can user DI to inject IUserProvider (or any other name) which should read the user details from JWT token. Also, you can fetch the user details directly form Claims/HttpContext instead of fetching it from Jwt token.

Comment: And now your DbContext has a completely unnecessary dependency on IHttpContextAccessor.  You should depend on only what you need, in this case you only need the ClaimsPrincipal (or IPrincipal).  And the sub claim won't always be the first claim in the collection.

Comment: Ok, I've changed my LINQ. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you've actually integrated into the ASP.NET Core authentication subsystem (i.e. `services.AddAuthentication` and `app.UseAuthentication`) then this is essentially handled for you. The JWT will be read to build a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance out of it, which then gets stored in `HttpContext.User`. Therefore, the user's username would be at the standard location of `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, or you can access it directly (and any other claims) via the `Claims` collection on `HttpContext.User.Identity`.

If the problem is that you need this information some place where you don't have access directly to `HttpContext.User` (basically anywhere outside of a controller or view), then you simply need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`. This requires two things:

1. You must add the `IHttpContextAccessor` service. It's not included by default for performance reasons. (That's not to say it has a severe impact on performance. It's simply that if you don't happen to need it, you can eek out a bit more performance by not including it. ASP.NET Core is all about including only what you need to include.) Anyways:

   **ASP.NET Core 2.1**

   ```
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   ```

   **Previous Versions**

   ```
   services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
   ```
2. Wherever you inject this needs to be part of the request pipeline, as otherwise, `HttpContext` will not exist. That shouldn't be an issue, since you're depending on there being a JWT present, anyways. Just bear in mind that you can't use this in a regular console app, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to inject an optional `IPrincipal` into DbContext?  That way you don't have to depend on HttpContext and the DbContext will be usable in console apps and easier to test.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the only problem I see with @Chris Prat's solution is that you now need to reference Asp.Net.Core assemblies in projects that does not actually have nothing to do with it.
For me a better solution would be to define a new class that has the required properties you want. Then use DI/IOC to register it as Func and pass that to DBContext.
ie.

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public Guid UserId{get;set;}
    public string UserName{get;set;
}
```

then in Startup.cs do something like this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ... services registration part ommited

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);
    builder.Register(context=>
    {
        var identityUser = context.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User;
        var userInfo = new UserInfo()
        {
            Name=//get it from identityUser.Claims 
            Id= //get it from identityUser.Claims
        }
        return userInfo;
    }).AsSelf()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Then in DbContext you have this (here I'm using Autofac IOC container, but any container that can register factories can do it like StructureMap, Ninject, Autofac...):

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    private readonly Func<UserInfo> _userInfoFactory;
    private UserInfo UserInfo => _userInfoFactory();

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, Func<UserInfo> userInfoFactory) : base(options) 
    {
        this._userInfoFactory = userInfoFactory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var someEntity = new SomeEntity()
        {
           ChangedByUserId = this.UserInfo.Id
           ...
        }
     }  
}
```

This is some cleaner solution that leads to more decoupling between projects.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your Startup.cs  ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In your Repository use Dependency Injection in the Constructor to add IHttpContentAccessor and you can get the UserId from the claims

```
public ModelRepository(DataContext dataContext, ILogger<ModelRepository> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
            _logger = logger;

            if(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            }           
        }
```

If you need more information from the user you can inject the UserManager as well

```
public ModelRepository(DataContext dataContext, ILogger<ModelRepository> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
            _logger = logger;

            if(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                user = await userManger.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            }           
        }
```